# Appending JTextArea from different class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, queue

Hi guys when i run my code, it works however i need help with showing my       System.out.println(data + " added to the queue"); in JTextArea(txt1) can someone help i need this please, i have been trying to do bu its not working so, i will need help thank you guyss

```
private Node front, rear;
private int currentSize;
MainFrame main = new MainFrame();

private class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;
}

public deneme2() {
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    currentSize = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (currentSize == 0);
}

public int dequeue() {
    int data = front.data;
    front = front.next;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        rear = null;
    }
    currentSize--;
    System.out.println(data + " removed from the queue");

    return data;
}

public void enqueue(int data) {
    Node oldRear = rear;
    rear = new Node();
    rear.data = data;
    rear.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        front = rear;
    } else {
        oldRear.next = rear;
    }
    currentSize++;
    System.out.println(data + " added to the queue");
}

public static void main(String a[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
    deneme2 queue = new deneme2();
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        queue.enqueue(s.nextInt());
    }
    s.close();
    queue.dequeue();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame();

        }
    });
```

}
}

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

```
public MainFrame() {

 JFrame frame=new JFrame();  
 JButton b1=new JButton("Load Up the Que");
 JButton b2=new JButton("Add to the Que");
 JTextArea txt1=new JTextArea();



 JTextArea txt2=new JTextArea();
 txt1.setEditable(false);

 b1.setBounds(50,100,180, 100); 
 b2.setBounds(50,300,180, 100);
 txt1.setBounds(600,100, 300,600);
 txt2.setBounds(300,300, 180,100);


 frame.add(b1);  
 frame.add(b2);  
 frame.add(txt1);
 frame.add(txt2);
 frame.setLayout(null); 
 frame.setSize(1000, 1500);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

Comment: Please include text in your question that explains in fair detail your code and your problem. We don't need begging or pleading, we need context that only **you** can provide.

Comment: Your JTextArea is declared locally in the class's constructor and so is not visible anywhere else in the class. Please consider refactoring the code and exposing in the class the fields that need exposing. As private instance (non-static) fields, of course. Then give the GUI class a public method that allows outside classes to put text into the JTextArea. Read up on "concurrency in Swing" to learn about threading issues as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry about that, how can i do that sorry i dont really know much i am trying to learn about these, sorry to be pain

Comment: Keep on learning as that's what matters most. What I'm suggesting is nothing more than general object-oriented principles: giving your class state (instance fields) and behaviors (public methods).  Good luck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels okay i will try, another question how can i use setText to write on it, as its an interget it gives error of int cannot be dereferenced, thank yo

Comment: Always [search on the error message first](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+int+cannot+be+dereferenced) (please check the links). Somewhere you're trying to call a method off of a primitive (int) variable, and that is not allowed by Java rules.

Comment: thanks for the help, i will try to do it. can you give me example of making private instance , i tried but i couldnt, i just need to somehow print into that text area and i will done my coursework which is due by 00 today aha